# Auto-enter master password in KeePassX on launch

Tags: password, startup, autostart, keepassx

I use KeepassX only for unimportant sites and it's set up to autostart. Entering password every time is quite annoying.

Comment: Have you considered using a *key file* instead of a *password* as a master key for the database?

Comment: @gertvdijk Wouldn't it be too unsecure if I just store it on my disk?

Comment: Of course it is insecure. But you wanted to unlock your KeePassX database without entering the password, which is insecure in *any* way you implement it. If you would create a script to open it and entering the password for you, it will imply to store the password in plaintext on your disk. **You're asking for something insecure.**

Comment: Have you considered investing in a barcode scanner or a macro keyboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start KeePassXC on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210158/start-keepassxc-on-boot)

Comment: @karel I'm not using Linux currently, so can't check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash script on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool type yourpassword
xdotool key Return
```

Comment: what is `xdotool` ?

Answer (score 0):

Truly, I am beginner, I run script from desktop, I use gnome-keyring, it is 50% working, sometimes it fails to enter the password, so you need to run it again :)

```
#!/bin/bash
keepassx path/to/database.kdbx
sleep 3s
secret-tool lookup keepassx database.kdbx | xdotool type --window 'database.kdbx - KeePassX' --file '-'
```

The entry in gnome keyring I created according to this https://gist.github.com/dAnjou/b99f55de34b90246f381e71e3c8f9262