# Unlocking keepassxc database on login...so close, but how to remove remaining issue?

Tags: bash, keepassxc

Based on this extremely useful answer [Start KeePassXC on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210158/start-keepassxc-on-boot/1210421#1210421)  I've almost got the desired result of unlocking `keepassxc` on login to work.

However, I (and another user who answer-commented about the same issue) have one problem remaining that keep it from being useful.  Namely, per the linked answer, I give the command...

`secret-tool lookup keepass <database_name> | keepassxc --pw-stdin <path-to-your-database>.kbdx`

...and this works in that `keepassxc` is started... but I get this prompt on the next line after the command

`Database password:`

and the script hangs waiting for input.

The parts of the script work... I can issue

`secret-tool lookup keepass <database_name>`

and I get the right password typed out.

I can issue

`echo <password> | keepassxc --pw-stdin <path-to-your-database>.kbdx`

and it starts `keepassxc` and logs in... but I still get the prompt and the script hanging.

If I do

`echo <password> | keepassxc --pw-stdin <path-to-your-database>.kbdx &`

I still get the prompt and hang, but I can hit `enter` and it works.

So it appears that I need to supply an `enter` somehow?

- Ubuntu version: 18.04
- keepassxc version: 2.6.4

Comment: @user68186 yes, bash on Ubuntu 18.04. The author of the answer I linked didn't have any trouble either, but I and some other user did. I just don't know what the difference is.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for all your effort! If I type just `keepassxc &` in a terminal and press enter, the gui app opens, and I get the prompt back. The GUI app continues running. That seems to contradict what you say, but it's probably just that I don't understand.

Comment: You have autologin enabled? That would explain why `secret-tool` asks for a password: it is not unlocked yet.

Comment: @vanadium I don't have autologin enabled. The `secret-tool` is not asking for my sudo password. Rather KeePassXC is not able to read the password from `stdin`. Note, when we use `secret-tool lookup...` without the pipe, we see the password KeePassXC should see.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I indeed misunderstood what you said about the use of &, I got it backwards.

Comment: I am using this with flatpak. To store the password in the keyring: `secret-tool store --label="KeePassXC vanadium" keepass vanadium`, to launch keepassxc in autostart: `sh -c "secret-tool lookup keepass vanadium | /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=keepassxc --file-forwarding org.keepassxc.KeePassXC  --pw-stdin /home/vanadium/Dropbox/KeePassXC/vanadium.kdbx`

Comment: What is your version of KeepassXC?

Comment: @vanadium that's a great question and I'll edit it into the post. It's 2.6.4, I got it from the phoerious ppa

Comment: I see the same when running this in a terminal. I never noticed it because you do not see that from an autostart (or when launched from a shortcut key). So I was not knowing I had a problem until now ;)

Comment: @vanadium I am not averse to putting it in an autostart, I'll try that. That was my eventual goal anyway.

Comment: @vanadium it works for me as an autostart as well. If you care to add an answer stating that, I'll be glad to accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: OK, I just finished an answer giving some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

What you see is normal behaviour. The terminal will be released only once KeePassXC terminates.

**Long answer**

The `Database password:`  prompt that you see on the terminal is a result of the `--pw-stdin` option you provided to the `keepassxc` option. Since there is a pipe, standard input is not your keyboard, but the output of the previous `echo` command.

As long as KeepassXC is running, your prompt is blocked. That is normal and happens with any other program. For example, try starting `nautilus` at the terminal.

You can release the prompt by moving that process to the background: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then type `bg` to continue running the process in the background. `fg` will bring it to the foreground again. That is "traditional" terminal practice.

With the process on the foreground, the terminal will be released when you quit KeePassXC, either from quiting it in the graphical user interface, or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

This behavior is unnoticed when you do not run the command from a terminal emulator, e.g. from a desktop launcher or from a shortcut key binding, or even using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog.