# Start KeePassXC on unprotected PC without password on boot

Tags: bash, login, password, keepassxc

I have a laptop at my home and I have no password at startup. I also have gnome keyring autologin enabled. The only thing that really bugs me, is that I need to enter my 40 character password for KeePassXC database, each time I boot my laptop. I would like that KeePassXC boots without password, aslong as I am working from home. When I travel, I would like to re-enable password login.

I found an explanation at https://askubuntu.com/a/1210421/247771 how to set autostart up. The latter using `secret-tool lookup keepass <database_name> | keepassxc --pw-stdin <path-to-your-database>.kbdx` did not work for me, perhaps because I use autologin on gnome keyring.

The second approach using

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1234qwer | keepassxc --pw-stdin /home/adam/Dropbox/MyDBExample.kbdx
```

did also not work. When I try to execute the above bash manually, I get a `Session management error` and KeePassXC window appears, asking for a password:

[image]

How can I enable auto login for KeePassXC?

Comment: DId you try the second method as an autostart? When I run these scripts manually, I get the prompt, but they work as autostarts. Alternately, there are posts on here about unlocking the keyring on autologin, but IIRC they involve removing the password.

Comment: Did you change the hostname of your computer recently? Then perhaps check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986964/qt-session-management-error